# How to solve Xcode validation errors when uploading app to iTunes connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode10

For the past 4 days, I have been going crazy trying to upload my iOS mobile application to iTunes connect and so far I have only received errors during validation checks. [Errors: ITMS-90046,ITMS-90685,ITMS-90347]

I have checked several stack overflow solutions ranging from hard quitting Xcode, checking signatures, verifying capabilities, deleting developer profiles and many others. On the other hand, I have also used google to search for anything that could help my case and so far nothing.

This is exactly the error that I have.

> ```
> App Store Connect Operation Error
> ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your
> application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that
> are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value
> 'applinks:appname.page.link/WSBG' for key
> 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in
> 'Payload/appname.app/appname' is not supported."
>
> App Store Connect Operation Error
> ERROR ITMS-90685: "CFBundleIdentifier Collision. There is more than one bundle with the CFBundleIdentifier value '' under the iOS
> application ''."
>
> App Store Connect Operation Error
> ERROR ITMS-90347: "Bad bundle identifier. The bundle identifier '' of the application extension
> appname.app/PlugIns/OtchitandaNotification.appex should start with the
> application's bundle identifier 'com.appname.App' and not contain more
> than one period “.” after the application's bundle ID."
> ```

1. [Link for above error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K17Ew.png)
2. [Link for entitlements
   screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SEdc.png)
3. [Link for signing settings in build settings
   screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dupia.png)

What options would you advise me to try to solve these issues? I am literally lost and have tried many solutions that have failed.

For the first error, there are various articles that stated that dynamic links and web credentials should be were I have placed them.

For the second and third error, I have double checked both bundle identifiers on my targets which are composed of "AppName" and "appNameNotification" with the latter being an extension.

Comment: In the 3rd screenshot, your Release configuration should be iOS Distribution not iOS Developer.

Comment: @prex thank you for that. Have corrected this mistake. Regarding the other issues, so far no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for error 2 and 3. I was using two targets, one being the main app and another being an extension of the main app.

I made the mistake of using a single bundle identifier for both targets when I should have two because when I use an extension I have to consider it to be a second application.

Therefore, the solution was to create a new app ID with a bundle identifier specifically for the extension alongside provision profiles for that bundle ID (extension target).

XCode is annoying